# Why doesn't the try/except catch the NameError?

Tags: try-catch, except

def grades(score):
try:
if score >= .9:
return 'A'
elif score >= .8:
return 'B'
elif score >= .7:
return 'C'
elif score >= .6:
return 'D'
elif score <= .59:
return 'F'
else:
return 'Bad Score'
except NameError:
print('bad score')

x = grades(perfect)

print(x)

Answer (score 0):

the error/exception is happening at x = grades(perfect) and not within your function grades, where you have your try/except block. The compiler won't allow your undefined variable (perfect) to be used as an argument.

Although it doesn't make a lot of sense, try the following:

```
try:
  x = grades(perfect)
except NameError:
  print('bad score')
```

For the function grades to make sense in regards of try/catch, you would always pass a defined variable as an argument and then cast the variable as a float (for this specific case). If the variable is a string, then you can catch a ValueError Exception. If the variable is = None, then catch a TypeError exception:

```
def grades(score): 
  try: 
    _score = float(score)
    if _score >= .9: return 'A' 
    elif _score >= .8: return 'B' 
    elif _score >= .7: return 'C' 
    elif _score >= .6: return 'D' 
    elif _score <= .59: return 'F' 
    else: return 'Bad Score' 
  except ValueError: print('bad score')
  except TypeError: print('bad score')
```

x = grades('perfect')

print(x)

or

perfect = None

x = grades(perfect)

print(x)